# Creating release from bamboo to nexus oss

Tags: nexus

We push the maven project code from bit bucket to bamboo.It gets build in bamboo and generates the artifact which is basically an war file(which includes the bamboo build number ).We have used the curl command to push these artifacts from bamboo to nexus oss.

1.Whether the nexus after getting the artifacts uploaded from bamboo creates any release number

2.Can we create the release number in nexus?

3.How can we create the release in nexus back to bamboo ?

4.Is this possible? Are any plugins available or can we use any kind of scripts?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend configuring your maven build to use the [maven-deploy-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) to upload artifacts to Nexus in a consistent manner.
Here's a short blog post that describes pushing a war file: http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2015/02/27/setup-local-nexus-repository-and-deploy-war-file-from-maven/